# Add parameter to dataAdapter.fill()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, parameters, sqldataadapter

I am trying to add a parameter to a sqlDataAdapter.  I have tried to use parameters.add() but the adapter is not a sqlCommand.  Here is some of my code.

```
Private Sub convertToCSV(ByVal SqlQuery As String)
        Dim Dt As New DataTable()
        Dim SqlCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=db;Initial Catalog=productionservicereminder;User Id=id;Password=pass;")
        Dim Ada As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, SqlCon)

        Ada.Fill(Dt)

  Public Sub excSP(ByVal ReprtID As Integer, ByVal pgid As Integer)

 convertToCSV(sql4)

End Sub
```

Basically I am trying to do something like this:

```
Ada.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pgid", pgid))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the SelectCommand:

ADA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pgid", pgid))

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx